# 'loss: nan' during training of Neural Network in python

Tags: python, neural-network, training, gradient-descent, epochs

I am training a neural network in python. But the accuracy is very low.

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.10      1.00      0.19      1536
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00      1517
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00      1464
           3       0.00      0.00      0.00      1504
           4       0.00      0.00      0.00      1535
           5       0.00      0.00      0.00      1468
           6       0.00      0.00      0.00      1503
           7       0.00      0.00      0.00      1499
           8       0.00      0.00      0.00      1503
           9       0.00      0.00      0.00      1471

    accuracy                           0.10     15000
   macro avg       0.01      0.10      0.02     15000
weighted avg       0.01      0.10      0.02     15000
```

It seems that during training of the first epoch the loss value returns nan.

```
    epoch 1: 64/2483 loss: 3.520028:   0%|          | 0/39 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
      after removing the cwd from sys.path.
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
      after removing the cwd from sys.path.
    epoch 1: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626681: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 63.65it/s]
        mean epoch 1 loss: train:  nan val: 2.449664
    epoch 2: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 62.68it/s]
        mean epoch 2 loss: train: 2.434646 val: 2.449432
    epoch 3: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 63.45it/s]
        mean epoch 3 loss: train: 2.434639 val: 2.449432
    epoch 4: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 63.47it/s]
        mean epoch 4 loss: train: 2.434639 val: 2.449432
    epoch 5: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 64.81it/s]
        mean epoch 5 loss: train: 2.434639 val: 2.449432
    epoch 6: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 63.85it/s]
        mean epoch 6 loss: train: 2.434639 val: 2.449432
    epoch 7: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 63.89it/s]
        mean epoch 7 loss: train: 2.434639 val: 2.449432
    epoch 8: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 66.05it/s]
        mean epoch 8 loss: train: 2.434639 val: 2.449432
    epoch 9: 2483/2483 loss: 2.626581: 100%|██████████| 39/39 [00:00<00:00, 68.74it/s]
............etc
```

Im trying to normalize the input dan fill the nan input using:

```
    #fill the nan
    col_mean = np.nanmean(features, axis = 0) 
    inds = np.where(np.isnan(features))
    features[inds] = np.take(col_mean, inds[1]) 

    #normalize
    features = np.interp(features, (features.min(), features.max()), (0, +1))
```

but the accuracy still doesn't change.

Comment: Could you tell us which framework you are using? Is it Keras?

Also, maybe I am blind, but I don't see any `nan` in the output you posted. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Considering the warning in the first line, any chance you send the zero to log function?  This issue could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229340/divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log-when-not-dividing-by-zero/36229376

Comment: im sory its not nan problem, but the akurasi is only 10%